# Is there such a payment method in paypal?

Tags: paypal

What I want is pretty much like [**Buy Now button**](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside),but I want the price to be changed on the fly,not set fixed before hand.

Is there such a payment method in paypal?

Comment: Changed on the fly by who? The user?

Comment: According to how many things he/she buys.

Comment: can you give an example/use case?

Comment: All b2c sites that support paypal are example?

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own shopping cart. You will have a Buy Now button after the checkout phase, and there you can set the prices the way you want them by manipulating the form.

Comment: This site lists of all the variables that can be used: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables